# Calling a non-static method written below Main, from Main

Tags: java, methods

I have a question about Java. I'm trying to do an end of semester project in my intro Java class and I'm having problems calling a method in Main.

I'm trying to do basically the same thing I used to do in Intro to c++ where you create a method (`public void Menu()`) below the main routine and then call that method (`Menu();`) in the main routine. I keep getting the "`non-static method cannot be referenced...`" error.

Apparently there is something in Java about how everything has to be in reference to an object, but this method isn't from a class file. It's just written below Main in the run file. Is any of this even possible?

Comment: You seem to be hung up on that fact that a method is written below (actually to the right of) another. Its location within a class declaration makes absolutely no difference.

Comment: Whatever, that's not the point. I just remember in C++ we did this almost every single assignment and there was never any problems calling the methods. We also never used the word "static" for anything.

Comment: Don't make assumptions like that. You're working with two different languages.

Comment: Ok so one last question here. The two basic ways I've seen is: Make everything static, or call the method by doing "new class().Menu()". Is either one of these better than the other?

Comment: Use `static` methods for pure functions with no side effects. Use instance methods for most everything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The location of a method doesn't change how a method can be used. If a method has the `static` modifier, you can't call a non-static method into it without using the class' constructor as a pointer. Further, because you asked in another answer, a variable cannot be called into a static method unless that variable too is static, but again it can be pointed to with the constructor.

```
class MyClass {

   String s = "";//can't be used in a static method
   static String t = "";//can be used in a static method

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       testOne();//this will break
       testTwo();//this is valid
       MyClass myClass = new MyClass()
       myClass.testOne();//this is valid

       System.out.println(s);//this will break
       System.out.println(t);//this will not break
       System.out.println(myClass.s);//this will not break
   }

   public void testOne() { }
   public static void testTwo() { }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You say

> Apparently there is something in Java about how everything has to be
>   in reference to an object, but this method isn't from a class file.
>   It's just written below Main in the run file. Is any of this even
>   possible?

You might be dealing with one of these issues:

1. You may have mistakenly defined your method outside of the class. 
   Fix: Your method should be part of the class. In Java, unlike C++, all your methods must be defined inside the class. If this was the issue, I am not sure how your code even compiled.
2. Your method is not static but you are trying to call it from a static method (the `main()` is a static method). 
   Fix: If you want to call your method without using an object, then declare your method as a static method. something like "`public static void menu()`".

Answer (score 0):

You can't call a non-static method from a static method. Either make your non-static method static, or create an instance of the class and use that to call the non-static method.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class test {
    static int num1;
    int num;
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        method1();  //illegal not a static method
        method2();  //legal static method
        new test().method1(); //legal accessing through the object reference
    }

    public void method1(){
        num1++;
        num++;
    }

    public static void method2(){
        num1++;
        num++;  //illegal static variable is bounded to class, others bounded to object you can't access without object reference
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant call a non static method from main(). Just create a new object of your class, say Menu m = new Menu(); and call your method from m, say m.myMethod();

Answer (score 0):

Your "run file" as you call it, is actually a `class` with a `static` method (`public static void main(String[] args) ...`) ->(FYI: in Java it's called methods not function or routine :).
That's because only a `static` method is *always* there without the need to create an object of that class. So if you run your program, Java expects that method. Since it *needs* to be there, it needs to be `static`.

Now if you have a method that, lets say calculates double of a number, that method only needs one number to do its calculations and it will *always* return the same result for the same number. Then you can make that method static -> you don't need a complex Object around it to calculate the double:

```
public class MyMath{

    public static int doDouble(int n){
         return n*2;
    }
}
```

So back in your `main` method you could call that method like this:

```
public class MyProgram{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int result = MyMath.doDouble(3);    // this will call the static function doDouble in the class MyMath
    }

}
```

You don't need to create an Object of your MyMath class to access that method; it is *always there*.

But if you have a class that is supposed to be instantiated as Objects, then you need to create an object of that class first:

```
 public class Person{

     private String name;

     public Person(String name){       // creates the person object and assignes the name
         this.name=name;
     }

     public void setName(String name){   // sets the name
         this.name=name;
     }

     public String getName(){         // gets the name
         return name;
     }

 }
```

That basic class needs to be an object if you want to use it

```
public static void main(String[] args){

      Person jon = new Person("Jon");    // create the object of that class
      System.out.println("his name is" + jon.getName());  // call a function from that object and print the result
}
```

You might have noticed that within the Person class there is no `static` method at all. So you need to *always* have an object of that class to access its methods (independent of the context, it does not matter if you are in a static method like your main or some other Object that is not static)

Because now imagine you would do something like that:

```
  System.out.println("his name is" + jon.getName());   // will print "Jon"
  jon.setName("Peter");     // sets a new name  
  System.out.println("his name is" + jon.getName());   // will print "Peter"
```

It is still the same `Person` Object, but it changed (you called the setName method). And since that Object changed it will now return the name "Peter" instead of "Jon".

But Java cannot know if the object changes or not.. it cannot know if `jon.getName()` will be available. Its result depends on the Object. So it is *not* `static`.

Long story short: that's why a method needs to be `static` if you simply want to call that method from your main.